# How would a sorcerer in a setting where sorcerers are illegal hide their magic? or just hide in plain sight?

Tags: society, magic

Moving [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138021/how-would-a-sorcerer-in-a-setting-where-sorcerers-are-illegal-hide-their-magic) to here as I didn't pay attention to the rules ;w; my bad.

"I have a homebrew setting where pretty much anything outside of wizardry and general clerical magic is very illegal, like to the point of being either killed, confined or deported out of the country. Likewise, one of my PCs is playing a draconic sorcerer unaware that his magic is actually sorcery, subclassing into wizard.

How could I reason in-universe that he's been able to live his life and perform magic without being found out? Any advice is greatly appreciated."

*To clarify: **The player is aware that his character is a sorcerer**, and wants this to be a component of his story. 
When I say subclassing into wizard, I intend to mean he's spent some of his life studying arcana/wizardry in-universe and is mechanically taking wizard levels. That's was a bad on my part.*

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a sorcerer and a wizard?  We can distinguish a cleric as drawing his power through religious rituals, but the other two seem synonymous

Comment: You can ask it here. But you have to make it clear what the difference would be to an outside observer. If a sorcerer and a wizard cast the same spells, use the same techniques and so on, there really is no way to tell. First you must delineate what the difference might be, and if the average person knows it.

Comment: @nzaman Sorcerer, as I understand it in DND 5e is a magic user that draws directly from magic within themselves, either from a bloodline or inherent magical gift from a powerful being (dragons, gods ect.). Wizards are scholars of magic, they study and practice magical feats through preexisting power within the world itself. They, themselves aren't inherently magical but can tap upon what already exists in the world to cast magic through others research and findings. I hope that makes sense ;;;

Comment: @ErinThursby Yeah that's the real killer here as wizards mechanics wise have to have a spellbook, component pouch or arcane focus to channel their use of magic while sorcerers can just *do* it. So it wouldnt exactly be the same, although I could reason it to be that while somebody with expertise on this sort of thing would know the general public wouldnt tell the difference.

Comment: @Maroogle: I get that, but as Erin Thursby said, how does and untrained, external observer know the difference. The cleric starts a holy chant (or infernal, if they're serving that sort), and is limited in the type of magic they can cast; what is the difference between the wizard and sorcerer?

Comment: Also is there a governing body for Wizards? something akin to the unseen university? as if using a spell book is all that "the average person" knows to differentiate between them then a sorcerer just pretending to  read from "Dibbler's Cookbook" while performing their magical feats would fool 99% of people. but if the UU investigates such people the its more about fooling the educated authorities

Comment: @nzaman Ah, I understand what you're getting at now. Like I said to Erin, it would be a fundementally different way of drawing power. I would say a wizard would have to prepare things such as scrolls if they wernt going to use a spellbook, say an incantation or do a specified set of actions and dedicate their focus to its casting. It's more methodical, while sorcerers would be more physical in their casting and not have to deal with any of that busywork, outside of focusing their attention on drawing upon that power. Hope that clarifies!

Comment: @BladeWraith There is a collection of houses that control sections of the settings continent as well as a ruling monarchy that oversees those houses. All of the families are either old wizard families, archfey or powerful beings that have allied or work in conjunction with the monarchy. Your point about the spellbook makes sense!

Comment: Hello @Maroogle and welcome to WorldBuilding. Your question being about a problem you encounter inside your world is good. What would be better is if you could remove the references to the D&D rules and lore and instead *explain*/*inline* these parts so your question can be understood from someone that is not versed in D&D (and optimally answered without having to know D&D lore & rules)

Comment: I've voted to hold this question as *"unclear what you're asking"*. Could you edit your question giving us more information about your homebrew setting specifics? There is not enough information for us to provide a meaningful answer, I think.

Comment: @Maroogle When I played, you memorized the spells beforehand--and you didn't need the book IN FRONT of you to cast later in the day. So to the outside observer, a wizard or a sorc casting fireball will pretty much look the same. Write up what the differences look like an edit your question. Basically--pick a spell. A sorc casts, a wizard casts. What are the differences? Would wiz community be able to educate non-magic casters in spotting a sorc since it's so illegal?? Please edit the question, every1 is not going to read comments.

Comment: Also you have the added problem of the character NOT being aware of the difference, so maybe they don't educate very well outside certain areas? If there's a marked difference then, they will know. If there isn't then it's hard to catch sorcerers without other magic users policing them. Not being found out is one thing, not being aware that you are a sorcerer is another....

Comment: You should re-made your question. We aren't in RPG SE so not everybody knows the difference between Wizard and Sorcerer, not what is homebrew or PC.

Comment: By the way, if a Sorcerer wants to seem like a Wizard it's quite simple. 1) Don't use Metamagic, **never**. 2) Buy a spell book and wrote fancy in-code text, everybody will think they are your spells even if they are just random words. 3) Only use spells that can use either Sorcerers or Wizards, never a Sorcerer-only spell, otherwise they will note you aren't a Wizard. 4) Buy an Arcane Focus or spell pouch. 5) If you have a dragon bloodline, don't level up, you don't want to have armoured skin nor wings or breath. 6) If you have wild magic... be careful.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate thought is: have the character pretend to be a wizard, as there is a lesser gap between them than with a cleric (divine magic user). This in turn requires several things:

- The character would need to finish the required education for a wizard
- Since you mentioned in one of the comments there is a body overseeing the wizard group, the character would need a valid wizard permit/badge/other form of documentation for that body
- The previous point could require an exam or something similar, so the character would need to know the tools a wizard uses and how to accurately mimic a wizard performing magic
- If there are limitations to what kind/type of magic the character can innately do, which a wizard is expected to do normally, the character would have to find a way to perform said magic, most likely through other magic items and such
- Should the draconic bloodline manifest in the character physically, then the character also needs to keep in mind how to dress to hide it